# Animating a UIView (that contains child components WITH constraints) by its constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I was recently trying to animate a UIView with a textfield inside of it(That has constraints) by its constraints. I successfully managed to move the UIView but for whatever reason, the textfield inside of it gets 'smushed' when the UIView moves and the X-Code debugger throws the error : `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` . I'm moving the UIView offscreen so perhaps this could be the reason why. My code is here:

```
        self.mainViewLeftConstraint.constant = self.menuView.frame.width
        self.mainViewRightConstraint.constant = self.mainViewRightConstraint.constant + self.menuView.frame.width


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

In the code above, the mainView is the width of the screen and the menuView is about half. Sorry if the question is a bit difficult to understand since it's hard to explain the issue without any type of visual guides.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of the storyboard?

Comment: Make sure the constraints on the text field are only between it and its super view.

Comment: @vacawama is right.. that means your text fields constraints are not set with the UIView you want to animate

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` signifies that the all the constraints of `UITextfield` is not w.r.t to `UIView` (superview of `UITextfield`). So when you are moving `UIView`, there is an ambiguity in satisfying all the constraints (w.r.t UIView + w.r.t some other view) of `UITextfield` at the same time.

Comment: I redid my constraints and made sure that they were all in the UIView but I'm still getting the same error. I read that this might be due to how I have two constraints on either side of the UIView I'm moving to the margins of the ViewController. Not sure how to fix this though.